# Operations on sublists

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I am currently wondering on an approach to split a list in sub-lists according to a given criteria. Because of the *didactic purpose* of this work, I do not use built-in functions.
IE, the following program should, given a list, return a list of lists, where each sub-list does not have duplicates and is in ascending order:

```
increment [4;4;10;20;5;30;6;10] = [[4;10;20];[5;30];[6;10]]
increment [5;6;4;3;2;1] = [[5;6];[4];[3];[2];[1]]
```

My best attempt so far is based on this chunk of code I produced:

```
let rec increment li [lo] = 
    match li with
        |[]         ->  [lo]
        |[x]        ->  [x]::[lo]
        |x::y::xs   ->  if x = y then
                            increment (y::xs) [lo]
                        elif x < y then
                            x::(increment (y::xs) [lo])
                        else
                            (x::(increment xs [lo]))::[lo]
```

Unfortunately, I fail in creating the list of lists. The principle is correct. It is based on the function I built, that correctly isolates an ascending list if present:

```
let rec incrementAux li = 
    match li with
        |[]         ->  []
        |[x]        ->  [x]
        |x::y::xs   ->  if x = y then
                            incrementAux (y::xs)
                        elif x < y then
                            x::(incrementAux (y::xs))
                        else
                            x::(incrementAux [])
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without using the built-in functions on the `List` module (purely as a learning exercise), then you just need to understand `map` and `fold` so you can implement them yourself.  I would start with [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).  Conveniently, you can easily implement `rev` in terms of `fold`, so that shouldn't be a problem.  Once you understand what each function does, you can implement them yourself like so:

```
let rec fold f state = function
| [] -> state
| head::tail -> fold f (f state head) tail

let map f list =
    [for item in list -> f item]

let rev list = 
    fold (fun acc cur -> cur::acc) [] list
```

Then, you can just substitute your own functions for the built-in functions in Szer's solution:

```
let input = [4;4;10;20;5;30;6;10]
let output = [[4;10;20];[5;30];[6;10]]

let increment = 
    fold (fun (last::rest as total) x ->
        match last with
        | [] -> [x] :: rest
        | h::_ as last ->
        if x > h then (x::last)::rest
        else if x = h then total
        else [x]::total) [[]]
    >> map rev
    >> rev

let testOutput = increment input
testOutput = output
```

Note, this implementation of `fold` is different from how F# `List` does it.  This is based on the simple Haskell example in the wikipedia article.  The functionality is the same, but the implementation is quite different, as F# actually uses a mutable accumulator and a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without recursion. `List.fold` with a little bit of memory could help:

```
let input = [4;4;10;20;5;30;6;10]
let output = [[4;10;20];[5;30];[6;10]]

let increment = 
    List.fold (fun (last::rest as total) x ->
        match last with
        | [] -> [x] :: rest
        | h::_ as last ->
        if x > h then (x::last)::rest
        else if x = h then total
        else [x]::total) [[]]
    >> List.map List.rev
    >> List.rev

let testOutput = increment input
testOutput = output // true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am more interested in an approach without the use of built in functions, allowing me, then, to better comprehend the  more basic elements of fsharp programming.