# F# : need help reversing order of ilist

Tags: list, f#

I must use the following data type:

```
type ilist = E | L of int * ilist
```

I can't seem to find much help on working with lists outside of the standard type online ( [1;2;3] )

I am to write a function that takes a lists and reverses the order

for example: reverse (L(1, L(2, L(3, E)))) would output  (L(3, L(2, L(1, E))))

So far here is my code:

```
 let rec reverse l = 
     match l with 
     | E -> failwith "Empty List"
     | L(h, E) -> h
     | L(h, t) -> // append tail and recursive call with rest of list?

 let list = reverse (L(1, L(2, L(3, E))))
 printfn "reversed list: %A" list
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operations on sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405408/operations-on-sublists)

Comment: In the linked duplicate, the built-in list type is still used, but the functions are defined.  You would just need to replace `[]` with your `E` case and `head :: tail` with your `L (head, tail)` case.

Comment: This looks like they are breaking lists into sublists? So I believe it is not a duplicate question, or was this just for referencing?

Comment: The original question is a little different, but the answer is the same.  The reverse function in the accepted answer should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are lacking is a convenient way to append an `int` to an `ilist`:

```
let rec append x l =
  match l with
  | E       -> L (x,E)
  | L (h,t) -> L (h,append x t)

printfn "%A" (append 4 list)
```

Now use this function in your last match case to append `h` to the reversed `t`:

```
let rec reverse l = 
  match l with 
  | E       -> E
  | L (h,t) -> append h (reverse t)
```

Note that it's probably better to just return an empty list when the input list is empty (`| E -> E`), because `failwith` is something very ugly you should only use in the rarest cases.

Also note that your second match case `| L(h, E) -> h` is wrong, because it returns an `int` instead of an `ilist`. But it is not needed anyway, so just remove it. The singleton list `L (h,E)` will be matched with `| L (h,t) -> ...` instead, which in turn recursively matches `t` with `| E -> E`.

Here is a working example: https://repl.it/repls/PhonyAdventurousNet